# Using includes in php

Tags: php, include, dreamweaver

I have a file that is called header (the header of my site).. I use that file in all my site. The problem is that it has this include in it:

```
include_once("../untitled/sanitize_string.php");
```

which means that a mistake may be thrown, depending on who calls the header file.

I have directories, subdirectories and subdirectories to the subdirectories.. is there a simple way to prevent this from happening.. Instead of taking the satize string include and placing it on every page and not in the header file

```
Warning: require_once(/untitled/sanitize_string.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\PoliticalForum\StoredProcedure\User\headerSite.php on line 7
```

Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required '/untitled/sanitize_string.php' (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\PoliticalForum\StoredProcedure\User\headerSite.php on line 7

Comment: Please post the contents of `sanitize_string.php`. It's likely it includes code that isn't properly error-handled for missing variables, etc. That is the problem to fix.

Comment: Make it relative to a defined path, such as the document root for your website. I use a constant to do this; there are several techniques for how to determine the path.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For php 5.3 you can do:

```
include_once(__DIR__ . '/../untitled/sanitize_string.php');
```

where `__DIR__` is the directory for the current file

For older versions you can use

```
include_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../untitled/sanitize_string.php');
```

where `__FILE__` is the path for the current file

Lets say you have the following structure:

```
/app/path/public/header.php
/app/path/public/user/profile.php
/app/path/untitled/sanitize_string.php
```

If your `header.php` includes `santitize_script.php` with a relative path like so:

```
include_once("../untitled/sanitize_string.php");
```

the php interpreter will try to include that file RELATIVELY to the current working dir so if you will do a request like `http://localhost/header.php` it will try to include it from `/app/path/public/../untitled/sanitize_string.php` and it will work.

But if you will try to do a request like `http://localhost/user/profile.php` and profile.php includes header.php, than header.php will try to include the file from `/app/path/public/user/../untitled/sanitize_string.php` and this will not work anymore. (`/app/path/public/user` beeing the current working dir now)

That's why is a good practice to use absolute paths when including files. When used in `header.php`,  the `__DIR__` and `__FILE__` constants will always have the same values: `/app/path/public` and `/app/path/public/header.php` respectively no matter where `header.php` will be used thereafter

Comment: what does _DIR_ give you ? so what if i get the current directory or file?

Comment: If you happen to know that the script will always run from a webserver, and you want to manage your include paths relative to the webserver document root (so that you don't have to tweak the '../' prefix for each directory), you can write your paths relative to GetVar('DOCUMENT_ROOT') instead of dirname(__FILE__).

Comment: i dont know what GetVar('Document_root") does and I dont understand how this helps...include_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../untitled/sanitize_string.php'); because if my file is in the same directory, what will happen, it will think of going up a folder.which is a mistake..and why not to use only document paths?!? why were relative paths invented?

Comment: @WithFlyingColors if your file is in the same directory as header.php you will obviously include it with a syntax like `include_once(__DIR__ . '/untitled/sanitize_string.php');`

Comment: if it is in the same directory I could use : untitled/sanitize_string.php..why do you need the magic constant.. It has no use and not relevant to my question. The only solution that I see is either change the include_path in php.ini like visionary said or be careful how I use my includes..  so if I use absolute paths in my whole site..will I have no problem?

Comment: Of course that you will have no problem as long as you use constants. The include path is an alternative, but not for big projects. For each included file the php interpreter will have to make a lookup to see if the file is in any of the listed include paths. So for example if you have an include path with 5 paths, for every included file it will do up to 5 file stats in the worst case. Another issue is that if you are using APC you cannot use apc.stat=false with relative paths. See https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=59312

Comment: that was I thinking and that was what was written in teh documentation visionary sent me: Using a . in the include path allows for relative includes as it means the current directory. However, it is more efficient to explicitly use include './file' than having PHP always check the current directory for every include.

Answer (score 5):

You may consider setting a global [include path](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path) while using [include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php).

Comment: so this is the best solution, even though, I sacrifice speed. The answers that other people gave me arent relevant..even if i use magic constants, and once i use ../  it tells the file to go up a directory and look there for a file..an exception is still thrown

Comment: @WithFlyingColors: with absoulte path you don't have any exception

Comment: so why dont everyone use absolute paths instead of relative paths?!

Comment: Absolute paths are brittle. Every time you move files around, you have to go back into the file to change the absolute path. Relative paths are more flexible if you arrange your documents in a modular, self-contained structure. Of course, if you change your module's location you have to update the relative paths. For a fairly standard project, the PHP include path, like the OS PATH, offers the most flexible solution.

Comment: hmm.. I prefer to go the conventional way and best practices, so I will avaoid the include path, and go with absolute paths. I dont move files around. So all I need is to include files like I write the path for a src property of an image or a link?

Comment: Please don't confuse what most people do with best practices. There are a lot of PHP "developers" who know nothing of software development best practices. If you can handle the trade-offs with an absolute path, that may be the simplest solution. But, as genesis said, there is also no reason not to use the include path for this very purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Use absolute path...

```
include_once('/home/you/www/include.php');
```

Comment: +1 - or if you want to avoid absolute paths, use the [`__FILE__`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) constant in `header.php` and make it relative to that.

Answer (score 1):

Use absolute path as yes123 said.

```
include_once(dirname(__FILE__)."/../untitled/sanitize_string.php");
```

Comment: I get this : ning: include_once(C:\xampp\htdocs\PoliticalForum\StoredProcedure\User/../untitled/sanitize_string.php) [function.include-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\PoliticalForum\StoredProcedure\User\headerSite.php on line 7

Warning: include_once() [function.include]: Failed opening 'C:\xampp\htdocs\PoliticalForum\StoredProcedure\User/../untitled/sanitize_string.php' for inclusion (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\PoliticalForum\StoredProcedure\User\headerSite.php on line 7

Answer (score 1):

You're going to have to use absolute paths here, as opposed to relative. I often set up some constants to represent important directories, using the old Server vars. Like so:

`define('MY_DIR',$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/path/to/yer/dir');`

Then, modify your include statement:

`include_once(MY_DIR.'/your_file.php');`

Comment: This way, too, if for some odd reason your file system's layout changes, PHP will still know where to find the file.